# XML Sorter or perhaps format

Tags: xml

im having a xml file which includes lots of "item Id's starting with number 100 and all the way to 14500 but they are not in any order and i would really want to know an why so i dont have to do this manually, i would appreciate any help!

[Item Id's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdkpd.png)

Comment: XSLT or XQuery will do it for you.

Comment: Hi would you mind helping me with the script for it please or atleast guide me to what to search

Comment: Please edit your question and add the following: (1) input XML, (2) logic to sort, and (3) desired output XML after logic is applied.